# How does water intake with meals influence digestion?

Tags: digestion, gastroenterology, water, stomach

I am trying to figure out how water intake during meals effects digestion. Particularly, what volumes of water would inhibit digestion versus benefit digestion. Additionally, if water benefits the digestive process, at what volume would it start to inhibit digestion.

I've read that excessive water intake could possibly inhibit digestion. Looking at the laws of chemistry and pH, it is apparent that acidity is exponential and in order to decrease stomach acidity to the point of inhibiting digestion, it would take huge volumes of water. But that does not take into account the dilution of the enzymes such as Pepsin which are also necessary for digestion. So excessive water intake may not dilute stomach acid, but it's effect on the dilution of stomach enzymes could possibly inhibit the digestion process.

Comment: Related: https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/3883/how-does-water-intake-with-meals-influence-digestion?rq=1

Comment: The possible duplicate addresses pH and not the dilutive effect on digestive enzymes.