# How long does someone with acid reflux who's just eaten have to wait before drinking water?

Tags: digestion, water, gastroenterology, gerd-acid-reflux, drinks

A friend recently told me that GERD patients (acid reflux) should not drink water with meals. I found [an article that explains the reasoning](http://www.livestrong.com/article/525960-does-drinking-water-increase-the-symptoms-of-acid-reflux/). Basically, water dilutes the stomach acid required for breaking down foods. Since acid reflux medication limits the amount of stomach acid produced, water can have a larger impact on digestion for these patients. Sadly, the article doesn't specifically say how long to wait after meals.

Does anybody know?

Comment: Related: https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/3838/can-gerd-be-caused-by-too-little-stomach-acid

Comment: Related: https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/3883/how-does-water-intake-with-meals-influence-digestion?rq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is drinking water during or after a meal better?](http://health.stackexchange.com/questions/1060/is-drinking-water-during-or-after-a-meal-better)

Comment: Another good find, @YviDe. However, acid reflux patients may have different experiences than the general population. I take a daily 30mg dose of Lansoprozale, which drastically reduces the amount of stomach acid my body produces.

Comment: oh, you're right, I didn't see the part about the medication! Deleting my vote to close...

Comment: I added that part to clarify the difference with the related question.